# SSIS Change date (add local timezone) in data flow

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, timezone, timezone-offset

In my SSIS package I read column type datetimeoffset(7) and write to column datetime2(7) (data flow task). Select in Source returns value i.e. '2015-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00' but in destination I got '2014-12-31 19:00:00.0000000'. This 5 hours difference is related to timezone on server which hosts sql service (both database and ssis package).

Any idea what is cause of this  datetime change?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to pertain to setting a datetime in the destination that hasn't happened yet on the server in the later timezone.

The following article should address your issue with several options for resolving:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-1/